# JSOM Start workflow, pass parameters, use in sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I am starting a sharepoint online workflow in JSOM and passing parameters, workflow in working fine but how can I access those parameters in sharepoint designer?

[image: JSOM]

[image: dseigner]

Comment: any help please??

Answer (score 0):

Now sure whether you find why it's not showing parameter name from drop down box.
Maybe someone search about SharePoint workflow parameter.
Before you use the parameter, you have to add 'Initiation Form Parameter' from SharePoint designer.
[image]